# what changes should i have to do to in my cpp code to get correct output?

Tags: c++

```
//Question
```

/*There are N seats in a row. You are given a string S with length N; for each valid i, the i-th character of S is '0' if the i-th seat is empty or '1' if there is someone sitting in that seat.

Two people are friends if they are sitting next to each other. Two friends are always part of the same group of friends. Can you find the total number of groups?

### Input

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first and only line of each test case contains a single string S.

### Output

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the number of groups.*/

### // my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    int n=1e6;
    
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        string g1;
        cin>>g1;
        int group;
        group = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<g1.length();j++){
            if(g1[j] == '1'){
                for(int h=1;h<n;h++){
                if(g1[j+h] == '1'){
                    h++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
                group++;
                }
            } else{
                continue;
            }   
             
        }
        cout<<group<<endl;
    }
        return 0;}
```

### Example Input

### 4

000

010

101

01011011011110

### Example Output

0
1
2
4

### //my output

0

0

0

9

Comment: I would suggest you hard code a test case that is failing and step through the code in a debugger to see what is happening and how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sample output, you suppose to count '1's between zeros, which is the number of groups you have. Here is your implementation with small correction to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
   //    int n = 1e6;  --> not used

   for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
       string g1;
       cin >> g1;
       int group;
       group = 0;
       for (size_t j = 0; j < g1.length(); j++) {
           if (g1[j] == '1') {
               group++;
               //skip all '1' before the first '0'
               while (g1[j] == '1' && j < g1.length())
                   j++;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << group << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: thankyou for your answer but may you please tell me the error in my code valeca

Comment: The way I understood it, is that you need to count how many groups of '1's the string has.  The description is not clear ( to me), so I just updated a bit yours implementation to count them.

Comment: you have understood correctly and your implementation is also correct but may you please check my implementation and tell error in my implementation or suggest me the way to do so.-valeca

Comment: I put a bunch of comments in your code to explain what needs to be changed and why. Removing comments would work, but I suggest you to add a couple of changes to improve the logic of  the implementation provided.
Check my answer below, as comment doesn't allow to post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// my code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    // you don't need n variable
    // it is appropriate to use the length of the string instead
    // it also will remove one warning for initialization
    int n = 1e6; 

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        string g1;
        cin >> g1;
        int group; // you can use int group = 0; avoiding the statement below
        group = 0;
        // size_t stringLength = g1.length();
        for (int j = 0; j < g1.length(); j++) {
            if (g1[j] == '1') {
                group++;  // you need to add it here to starts counting
                // better this way -> for (size_t h = 1; h < stringLength; h++) 
                for (int h = 1; h < n; h++) { // h < n && (j+h)<stringLength
                    if (g1[j + h] == '1') {
                        // you increasing h value twice - first in for statement, second here
                        // instead, you need to set j to j+h value 
                        //h++; 
                        // you just "moving" through the string till next'0'
                        j = j + h;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                // this will increase group count for each next '1' in the string
                // this is why you got 9 for the last string in your's example
                //group++;
            }
        }
        // this is not needed
        //else {
        //    continue;
        //}
    }
    cout << group << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}